# Is it right to call viewModel's method from view in Android mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm building android app using mvvm pattern. I heard that view is recommended not to contain business logic except for UI. I wonder that calling viewModel's method from view is alright.

For example, there is a method that add list A to list B (list A is user's selection).

```
fun setSelectedList(
    listA: ArrayList<Something>,
    listB: ArrayList<Something>
) {
    listB.addAll(listA)
} //written in kotlin
```

This method is called from view

Should this method be located in view? or should be located in viewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data to survive configuration changes like screen rotation, then you should put the method that modifies or stores data in `ViewModel` and then call that method from your view as and when required. You can refer [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I'm not asking how to remain data. What I'm wondering is to put a method that processes data into ViewModel to reduce View's code line and call the method from View is alright behave?

Comment: @고현석, It depends on how you prefer to do it. As a general convention, you should keep your View/Activity class as clean as possible. So moving data to ViewModel is the preferred choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your kindness